# How to update my local git branch

Tags: git

I have cloned a repo on my desktop and and I started working on one of the branch. Now I wish to update this branch with the remote branch(get all the recent changes) without committing my changes. How to go about this?

Answer (score 1):

git pull or git pull origin your_branch_name

Comment: when I do that I get : $ git pull
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details

    git pull <remote> <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

    git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> origin/release-pa-10.1

Comment: Your comment answers your question. Either do `git pull <remote> <branch>` or do `git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> <branch>`. For instance, you could run `git pull origin release-pa-10.1` to fetch and merge the `release-pa-10.1` branch into your current local branch.